# Why are not all Review types in the top bar?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

Question as per title, why are not all the review types in the bar indicated by the number of open tasks?

Right now the number only counts the amount of open suggested edits tasks, which leads to me forgetting to do the other asks.

I see that the Close Votes queue could be a problem (who wants to see 20K in their top bar?), but why are the others not being added?

As a request, if there are no further issues, it would be good to show all review tasks, minus the Close Vote queue temporarily.

Comment: There really isn't enough space for that in the to bar.  There's *already* a link to /review.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure if you entirely understood what I meant (or if I said it correctly). But I am talking about a combined count of all pending review tasks. No individual counts.

Comment: The current review queues are relatively new; suggested edits were, once upon a time, handled differently and that indicator was the only link to handle those. And suggested edits deserve to be handled relatively fast as they block everyone else from making more edits. The rest of the review queues have no such urgency.

Comment: On one hand, I don't want the top bar to be full of flashing lights and numbers. On another hand, clicking just to find empty queues (on some sites other than SO) is a bit annoying. Compromise solution: change the tooltip from: "help improve the site" to more informative: x close votes, y first posts, etc.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223460/why-are-only-suggested-edits-quantities-shown-in-the-toolbar - "A pending suggested edit on a post locks the post against modifications by users without the edit privilege. It's in a partially-locked state for a large number of users. So it's important to get them resolved as fast as possible."